# React Native - How to pass props between StackNavigators in react-navigation?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I am using authentication flow as describe in React Navigation doc: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/auth-flow.html

So basically, I have a SwitchNavigator like this:

```
import { createSwitchNavigator, createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

// Implementation of HomeScreen, OtherScreen, SignInScreen, AuthLoadingScreen
// goes here.

const AppStack = createStackNavigator({ Home: HomeScreen, Other: OtherScreen });
const AuthStack = createStackNavigator({ SignIn: SignInScreen });

export default createSwitchNavigator(
  {
    AuthLoading: AuthLoadingScreen,
    App: AppStack,
    Auth: AuthStack,
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'AuthLoading',
  }
);
```

In SignInScreen, after user is signed in I navigate to HomeScreen using:

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('App', { myData: 'myData' });
```

How can I get `myData` in HomeScreen? `this.props.navigation.state.params` is null in my case.

Answer (score 0):

If params it's undefined you need to use 
    this.props.navigation.state.getParam('myData','defaultValue')

You can see in https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-prop.html

Comment: getParam('myData') is null too. I guess this is because `App` screen, where I want to navigate, is a StackNavigator, not a screen. So params are pass to createStackNavigator. I don't know how to get it in HomeScreen.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. How did you fix it?

Answer (score 0):

if anyone of you is still getting null value while passing params to stacknavigator, is because you can't pass params to stacknavigator directly. it creates confusion as to which screen you are referring to in your stack while passing params.
 if you want to pass the params to the route inside of a stack, navigate to that route directly.
In case of the OP problem, there is a workaround for that

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('Home', { myData: 'myData' });
```

but its not the great way to pass props,I rather consider using Redux to manage the state of the whole application

for more detailed explanation check out [this](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/3787) github issue